# How to set new property for a file using as3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flex4

For example a Image file has some default property like "file type", "file size", "file name", "last modified" and ect, like that any possibility is there to set our new property (that is "file added by") in action script as3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. You might want to look into PHP and MySQL for that; specifically, [uploading files](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) and database management. You will want various users to be able to log in, and once logged in, they can upload a file. At that point you will input the file location and username (and whatever other properties you want) into MySQL via PHP. You can then use Flash to utilize your php to add files and update the "file added by", if you wish.